# SQL Extract max per category in one step

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, greatest-n-per-group

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Sector           Category         rec_coun
------           --------         ---------
A                25               53
A                24               1911
A                23               2010
A                ..               ..
A                1                190
B                25               787877
B                24               931231231
B                ..               ..
8                1                778787
..
C                1                6666
```

What I want to get is a table showing, for each Sector, the Category associated with the maximum number of records in that combination of Sector and Category i.e. something like this

```
Sector                Category        Max Recs
------                --------        --------
A                     23              2010
B                     24              931231231
....
```

in my example above.   I'd ideally like to do this in one stepo.   I've tried

```
select distinct [Sector], [Category], max(rec_cnt) 
from table
group by [Sector], [Category]
having rec_cnt = max(rec_cnt)
```

but no good.   I'd prefer to avoid an inner join in a nested query if possible but, saving the best for last. I'm actually on SQL Server 2000 which may make this trickier than it should be.

Comment: It is time to update to supported software.  SQL Server 2000 has been unsupported for many years.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that using nested `GROUP BY` should ok even on SQL Server 2000.

```
select t.[Sector], table.[Category], t.max_rec
from table 
join
(
  select distinct [Sector], max(rec_cnt) max_rec
  from table 
  group by [Sector]
) t ON table.[Sector] = t.[Sector] and table.rec_cnt = t.max_rec
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple window function use should do the trick:

```
select distinct [Sector], 
FIRST_VALUE(Category) over (partition by Sector order by rec_cnt desc) as [Category], 
max(rec_cnt) over (partition by Sector) as [rec_cnt]
from table
```

EDIT: Ok, this can't work as window functions were introduced only starting from SQL Server 2005. Please see answer from Radim, that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Sector, Category, Max(rec_cnt) as 'Max Recs'
From Table
Group By Sector, Category
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit how this answer will solve the problem, instead of posting code-only answer.